# Incorporating OOP in existing PHP

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation

I'm trying to incorporate the OOP principles with a web app I'm developing.

Given a class ImageData defined as

```
class ImageData {
  private $count;
  private $dirArray;

  public function __construct() {
    $count = 0;    
    $dir = "panos/thumbs";
    $dirCon = opendir($dir);

    while ($name = readdir($dirCon)){
      if (strtolower(substr($name, -3)) == "jpg"){
        $dirArray[]= $name;
      }
    }

    sort($dirArray);
    $count= count($dirArray);

    closedir($dirCon);
  }

  public function getCount(){
    return $this->count;
  }

  public function getArray(){
    return $this->dirArray;
  }

}
```

I want to use the information here to use in rendering a web page.  Within the specified div element, I have

```
$imageData = new ImageData();
$count = $imageData->getCount();
$data = $imageData->getArray();
```

However, `$count` and `$data` are not instanciated locally, and the information contained is not available for usage in the render code.  I've stepped through the code in xdebug, and the constructor assigns the expected values to `$count` and `$data`.  In Java and C, its not required for variables to be instanciated at declaration.  Is this true for PHP?

Comment: I think we need to see the rendering code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your contructor, you have to use `$this->count` instead of `$count`, same for `$dirArray`.

PS: You can in PHP classes only declare your variables as you did.

Comment: You gave a solution to the symptoms, yet you did not educate.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>***DISCLAIMER:*** since question obviously has been already answered, this is a **long form comment** on provided code.</sub>

When writing classes, you should try to avoid computation in the constructor. It makes for hard to debug code.

I would actually structure the code like this:

```
class ImageData {
    protected $count = 0;
    protected $dir = null; 
    protected $dirArray = null; 

    public function __construct( $dir = 'panos/thumbs') {
        $this->dir = $dir;   
    }

    public function getCount(){

       if ( is_array($this->dirArray) ){
           $this->initialize();
       }

       return $this->count;
    }

    public function getArray(){

       if ( is_array($this->dirArray) ){
           $this->initialize();
       }

       return $this->dirArray;
    }

    protected function initialize(){

       $this->dirArray = $this->findImages();

       sort($this->dirArray);
       $this->count = count($dirArray);

    }

    protected function findImages( $extensions = array('jpg') ){

       $files = array();
       $dirCon = opendir($this->dir);

       while ($name = readdir($dirCon)){
           $current = strtolower(substr($foo, strrpos($foo, '.')+1));
           if ( in_array( $current, $extensions ) ){
               $files[] = $name;
           }
       }

       closedir($dirCon);
       return $files
    }

}
```

First of all, i would recommend to use `protected` instead of `private`, if you do not now that you actually need them `private`. Because the `private` members of class are not "visible", when you extend the class.

The other thing would be to move the initialization of object to a position, when it is actually required. With minor modifications, this class would enable you to search folder repeatedly, or even search in different folders altogether.

If you want to learn how to utilize OOP in context of PHP, start by reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php . And you might find [PHP Object-Oriented Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210117) book to be a big help.

Comment: You educated, but gave no solution to the symptoms :). +1 for a great explanation though.